# Find average of numbers of specific cloumns

Tags: shell

I have a file with three columns, I need to find the average for 2nd and 3rd column for which the first column has a specific pattern.

Example file

```
15 3.43940 0.05112
15 3.45226 0.05160
15 3.43940 0.05139
16 3.45793 0.05512
16 3.45621 0.05516
16 3.47121 0.05632
16 3.44217 0.05490
17 3.48756 0.05957
17 3.53883 0.06203
17 3.47278 0.05917
17 3.52358 0.06166
17 3.46511 0.05911
18 3.51000 0.06389
18 3.57026 0.06685
18 3.64300 0.06868
```

The output should be 1st column 15, 2nd column average of the second column whose 1st column is 15, 3rd column average of the third column whose first column is 15. Like that for 16,17,18.

I have tried this code, but not my problem solved

```
awk '
NR>1{
    arr[$1]   += $2
    arr[$1]   += $3
   count[$1] += 1
}
END{
    for (a in arr) {
        print a " = " arr[a] / count[a]
    }
}
' input
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were thinking correctly to store the values in arrays, but here it is easier to read all values into arrays using `$1` as the key to `sum` each of `$2` and `$3` into separate arrays as the records are read keeping at count of the number of records summed in a third array. Then using the `END` rule, compute the averages and output the index and then the averages in their appropriate column.

One way would be:

```
awk '
    { a[$1]+=$2; b[$1]+=$3; c[$1]++ }
    END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]/c[i], b[i]/c[i] }
' file
```

Where `a[]` holds the sum of the 2nd column indexed by the first, and `b[]` holds the sum of the 3rd column indexed by the first. Finally `c[]` holds the count of the number of records each first column index appears.

**Example Use/Output**

Using your example input in `file`, you can copy/middle-mouse-paste into the terminal to obtain the following:

```
$ awk '
>     { a[$1]+=$2; b[$1]+=$3; c[$1]++ }
>     END { for (i in a) print i, a[i]/c[i], b[i]/c[i] }
> ' file
15 3.44369 0.05137
16 3.45688 0.055375
17 3.49757 0.060308
18 3.57442 0.0664733
```

Look things over and let me know if that is what you were looking for. Your description was a bit confusing, but I think that was it.

Comment: **note:** you posted your code while I was editing and you were really, really close! It looks like the only problem you were having was what to do in `END`. Let me know if you wanted a format other than I provided.